# create new column of concatenated substrings

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

Apologies for the noob question!

I'd like to be able to create a new column using the mutate function and some other combination of dplyr/stringr to extract substrings of text from "File" column and make "Image" column as shown in output below:

```
test<- data.frame(File= c("4301 TMA_Scan1_Core[1,2,A]_[10673,40057]_component_data.tif", "TA3150Scan1_Core[1,3,A][7006,42110]_component_data.tif"))

testoutput<- data.frame(File= c("4301 TMA_Scan1_Core[1,2,A]_[10673,40057]_component_data.tif", "TA3150Scan1_Core[1,3,A][7006,42110]_component_data.tif"),
                        Image = c("TA4301-2A", "TA3150-3A"))
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what is the logic of extracting `TA4301-1A` and `TA3150-1A` from `File` column? For 1st row from where does "TA4301" and"1-A" comes?

Comment: TA4301-1A etc are identifiers of each row that are compatible with downstream analysis in MATLAB. Dataset is >1e6 rows.

Comment: There is not `TA4301-1A ` in the first row for the example shared.

Comment: The example in first row requires TA to be added. example in second row does not. 1A is taken from within [1,1,A] from the last two characters

Comment: This is similar to ekoam's answer below using slightly different regex : `test$Image <- sub('(?:[A-Z]+)?(\\d+).*?\\[\\d+,(\\d+),([A-Z])\\].*', 'TA\\1-\\2\\3', test$File, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
test %>% 
  mutate(Image = sub("^\\D*(\\d+)[^][,]+\\[\\w+,(\\w+),(\\w+)\\].+", "TA\\1-\\2\\3", File))
```

Output

```
                                                         File     Image
1 4301 TMA_Scan1_Core[1,2,A]_[10673,40057]_component_data.tif TA4301-2A
2      TA3150Scan1_Core[1,3,A][7006,42110]_component_data.tif TA3150-3A
```

From left to right,

```
1. Match zero or more non-digit characters from the beginning
2. Match one or more digits; set it as the first capturing group
3. Match one or characters that are not "]", "[", or ","
4. Match the three values inside square brackets; set the last two as second and third capturing groups
5. Match remaining characters

^\\D*  (\\d+  )  [^][,]+       \\[\\w+,(\\w+),(\\w+)\\]   .+
   TA     3150   Scan1_Core      [  1 ,   3  ,   A    ]   [7006,42110]_component_data.tif
          4301   TMA_Scan1_Core  [  1 ,   2  ,   A    ]   _[10673,40057]_component_data.tif
```